# Score related jargon in sports

Tags: word-choice, jargon

I recently discovered that in the sport of tennis, a score of "0" is pronounced "love".  I have a few questions related to this discovery!

1. Is it common for different sports to have words that represent different specific score values, or for zero?
2. Is there a website or reference book you can recommend where I can find a list of such words?  I don't mean for one specific sport, but for as many sports as possible-- like football, basketball, soccer, baseball, billiards, and so on, all in one place.

Thank you.

Comment: It depends on the sport, of course. Each one is different.

Comment: I edited this question to make it more focused.  I believe this rephrasing still keeps the heart of what Antonia was asking.

Comment: I've closed this question for two reasons: 1) there are still two separate questions, and 2) questions asking for references are off-topic. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) carefully

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course, each sport is different.  This Wikipedia article and English StackExchange post discuss some examples that may interest you:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Names_for_the_number_0_in_English#Sport
https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/447437/word-for-a-zero-score-in-sports-bre-ame